# Changing a relation to become transitive

Tags: algorithms, transitivity

Given a binary relation $R$ on a finite set $S$, is there an efficient algorithm to transform $R$ to a transitive relation $R'$ by minimum number of addition or deletion of pairs $(x,y)$ to or from $R$ where $x,y \in S$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem (for symmetric relations) is in graph theoretic terms called [Cluster Editing](https://pacechallenge.org/2021/cluster-editing/) and is a well know NP-complete problem.

For digraphs, it had been studied under the name Transitivity Editing [Weller, M., Komusiewicz, C., Niedermeier, R. and Uhlmann, J., 2012. On making directed graphs transitive. Journal of Computer and System Sciences, 78(2), pp.559-574.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002200001100078X) as pointed out by idmean in a comment below, and is not surprisingly NP-complete.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002200001100078X seems to prove NP-hardness.